# jQuery: How to detect when user scrolls to the top again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the top of my site I have a bar with similar blog posts. 
**It should SlideUp (with jQuery) when the user have scrolled to the top again - so e.g. after he read the article.

How can I detect this situation and then show the bar in the head of my site?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can monitor `scroll` event of `window` element,and check its `scrollTop()` :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()  <= 0 ){
        // your code
    }
});
```

Comment: I would do `<= 0` because OSX have negative `scrollTop` (even tough it goes back to 0).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to check the scroll position with .scrollTop() in jquery.

So the idea is to bind an event on scroll to check the position periodically.

```
hasReadArticle = false
$window = $(window)
articleBottomPosition = ... # get the position of the bottom of the article 
timeout = nil

$window.on "scroll", (e) ->
   clearTimeout timeout if timeout

   timeout = setTimeout ->
     top = $window.scrollTop()

     # you might want to improve this to detect when the bottom of your window arrives at the bottom of the article.
     hasReadArticle = top > articleBottomPosition unless hasReadArticle

     if top <= 0 && hasReadArticle
       # $('your header').slideDown()
   , 100
```

A simpler way to do it would be to use [jquery-waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints). You would set a handler to detect when you get to the bottom of your article, then set a variable to remember this. Then set another handler to detect when you get to the top of the page (with direction == "up").